# How can I prevent or limit CRON during SimpleTest?

Tags: 7, cron, testing

I have a CRON job that tops up a huge cache table. Normally, it only updates a few records. But the first time it runs in a new installation, it has to load the entire table with thousands of requests to an external API. This gives SimpleTest a big overhead for any minor test in the module.

How can I skip or limit CRON when SimpleTest creates a new installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your module has some sort of variable to know how far back it needs to fetch data. You could initialize that in your setUp() method.

A module should not have to care if it is executed within a test or not. Instead, the test code should prepare the environment to whatever makes sense for the test.

If that for some reason doesn't work, you can add a variable_get() based check if it should fetch data or not. That might also be useful for local development, not just automated tests.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only way is to write your own signal like this.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to know directly whether SimpleTest is running. For now, I am checking a role that the module creates for users. If there are no users of that role, I assume its SimpleTest running and limit my CRON.

Answer (score 0):

This post is old, but for those who still search for an answer, here are the trick :

use the preloadRegistry method, and override the parent one, 
instead of using the setUp method.
Because Drupalwebtestcase::setUp() is calling preloadRegistry before 
drupal_cron_run()

So, in your test class extending DrupalWebTestCase, add something like this for example

```
protected function preloadRegistry(){
  parent::preloadRegistry();
  variable_set('activate_mymodule_cron', false);
}
```

Then in the hook_cron of your module : mymodule.module : mymodule_cron()
add this :

```
$active_cron = variable_get('activate_mymodule_cron', true);
if($active_cron) 
   do_something();
```